# Visual Studio - Grid Ruler for Winform Design

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, screen-resolution

Is there a ruler addin for Visual Studio available which I can use to measure my winforms based on resolution. I am developing on a machine which has very fine resolution, however my end users have several resolutions, causing my app to not display correctly on some machines. This is for winform development.

How do you guys handle screen resolutions in your development?

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more on this statement?

"however my end users have several resolutions, causing my app to not display correctly on some machines."

Every time I've built a WinForms app, it works on other resolutions so long as I don't build windows to be larger than the smallest screen I support. Are you referring to DPI issues?

Comment: yep! Dpi. My build machine is 1900x1600. The app looks great. Some of my users use 1024*768 and some 1280 * 1024 and a few 800 * 600 (yes). So on some screens you see the complete app, some you see half of the app and some really sucks.

Comment: You may find the following links useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(VS.80).aspx
http://flyingtriangles.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-make-net-windows-forms-scale.html

I'd be interested in if they help you or not. I may soon face the task of making my applications compliant with different DPI settings.